# Gradient Layer form as the form of a button in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need a gradient background on the button. I used Custome Renderer to do this. Here my code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof (EvoMotorOilApp.Droid.MyButtonRender))]
```

...

```
protected override void DispatchDraw(global::Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.DispatchDraw(canvas);

        var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, Height, 
            Color.FromRgba(255, 255, 255, 255).ToAndroid(), 
            Color.FromRgba(70, 70, 70, 50).ToAndroid(),
            Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Repeat);

        var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint() {
            Dither = true,
        };
        paint.SetShader(gradient);

        canvas.DrawPaint(paint);


    }
```

But as a result  gradient layer extends beyond the button and hes have acute angles. How to do that would form gradient was as like button form?
There a screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8C-lgUpGFGDVzhVUzJrMm01cFU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set control background color to `GradientDrawable`:

```
public class GradientButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var gradient = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TopBottom, new[] {
                Color.FromRgba(255, 255, 255, 255).ToAndroid().ToArgb(), 
                Color.FromRgba(70, 70, 70, 50).ToAndroid().ToArgb()
            });

            Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gradient);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use `StateListDrawable` to set different colors for normal/pressed/disabled button states.