# Set Gradient as Button Color Renderer

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and I'm trying to set a gradient as a button color.
I have the exactly same problem as this guy: [Gradient Layer form as the form of a button in Xamarin.Forms Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32462632/3154381)

But the given answer is not quite what I'm looking for.

The answer is successful but it set all the button as the gradient.

I.E.: The guy had a problem that only the background was painted, the given answer sets the whole button, I want to set the color of the button itself and keep the padding.

[Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50117/gradient-layer-form-as-the-form-of-a-button) I probably have why the code it's not working, how to use the answer and and make this work??
Edit:
Here is my code:

```
public class GenericButton:Button
{
    public Xamarin.Forms.Color StartColor { get; set; }
    public Xamarin.Forms.Color EndColor { get; set; }
}
```

With this code I get the backround beyond the button:

```
public class GenericButtonRenderer :ButtonRenderer
{
    private Xamarin.Forms.Color StartColor { get; set; }
    private Xamarin.Forms.Color EndColor { get; set; }

    protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, Width, Height,
            this.StartColor.ToAndroid(),
            this.EndColor.ToAndroid(),
            Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Clamp);
        var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint()
        {
            Dither = true,
        };
        paint.SetShader(gradient);
        canvas.DrawPaint(paint);
        base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            var btn = e.NewElement as GenericButton;
            this.StartColor = btn.StartColor;
            this.EndColor = btn.EndColor;                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"          ERROR: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}//See result here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZpuX.png
```

The second thing I tried, with this I get the gradient correct but the button loses its layout:

```
public class GenericButtonRenderer :ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            var btn = e.NewElement as GenericButton;
            var gradient = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TopBottom, new[] {
            btn.StartColor.ToAndroid().ToArgb(),
           btn.EndColor.ToAndroid().ToArgb()
        });
            Control.Background=gradient;                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"          ERROR: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}//See result here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CDtG.png
```

Comment: Please, make some effort and post whole code here. Leave the links to other topics, but post you code with showing places where you have problems and how you suspect it can be solved.

Comment: My code is exactly like the code in links.

Comment: It does not matter. Make it easier for other people give you an answer. You want an answer - just post all code here, it much easier to look everything in one place then going by several links.

Comment: Okay, will do it later. I'm not in the computer right now.

Comment: Done. BTW the code is based from here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44884/guide-create-a-gradient-background-without-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to a workaround that isn't exactly what I'm looking for, will go with it until I find a better answer (will not work on this any more).

So my buttons are inside a grid and they are the only components of the grid, so I just added the following to the grid and the buttons will not got up to the bottom of the screen. (But the top padding it's not working.)

```
Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Padding = new Thickness(5,5,5,5),
            ColumnDefinitions =....
```

Will not select this answer yet as I still have hope that someone will find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend ButtonRenderer and customize the Background property of native control.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Extends <see cref="Xamarin.Forms.Button"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class ExtendedButton : Button
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Bindable property for button background gradient start color
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly BindableProperty StartColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("StartColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ExtendedButton), Color.Gray); 

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the background gradient start color
        /// </summary>
        public Color StartColor 
        {
            get { return (Color)this.GetValue(StartColorProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(StartColorProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Bindable property for button background gradient end color
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly BindableProperty EndColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("EndColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ExtendedButton), Color.Black);  

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the background gradient end color
        /// </summary>
        public Color EndColor
        {
            get { return (Color)this.GetValue(EndColorProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(EndColorProperty, value); }
        }
    }

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using NewHelloWorld.Droid.Renderers;
using NewHelloWorld;



[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedButton), typeof(ExtendedButtonRenderer))]
namespace NewHelloWorld.Droid.Renderers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class ExtendedButtonRenderer.
    /// </summary>
    public class ExtendedButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when [element changed].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">The e.</param>
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            UpdateGradientBackground();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the <see cref="E:ElementPropertyChanged" /> event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="PropertyChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.PropertyName == ExtendedButton.StartColorProperty.PropertyName || 
                e.PropertyName == ExtendedButton.EndColorProperty.PropertyName || 
                e.PropertyName == ExtendedButton.BorderColorProperty.PropertyName ||
                e.PropertyName == ExtendedButton.BorderRadiusProperty.PropertyName ||
                e.PropertyName == ExtendedButton.BorderWidthProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                UpdateGradientBackground();
            }

            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }

        //Called 
        protected override void UpdateBackgroundColor()
        {
            base.UpdateBackgroundColor();

            UpdateGradientBackground();
        }

        //Sets the background gradient color
        private void UpdateGradientBackground()
        {
            var button = this.Element as ExtendedButton;
            if (button != null)
            {
                int[] colors = new int[] { button.StartColor.ToAndroid(), button.EndColor.ToAndroid() };
                var gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TopBottom, colors);
                gradientDrawable.SetGradientType(GradientType.LinearGradient);
                gradientDrawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
                gradientDrawable.SetCornerRadius(button.BorderRadius);
                gradientDrawable.SetStroke((int)button.BorderWidth, button.BorderColor.ToAndroid());
                this.Control.Background = gradientDrawable;
            }
        }
    }
}
```